# Operador de divisão inteira python

Tags: python

Alguém sabe explicar o o porquê dessa função retornar `-2` e não `-1`?

```
print(-3//2)
```

O operador `//` não devolve a parte inteira da divisão?

Comment: Seja bem vindo George, este link te ajudará: https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/comportamento-inesperado-na-divisao-inteira/

Comment: Vale alertar que o link que o Luiz Augusto enviou está em python2, então leia `3 // 2` quando você ver `3 / 2` no artigo. Não achei uma documentação oficial que explique, mas tem um [artigo da Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-2-vs-python-3-practical-considerations-2#division-with-integers) que explica.

Comment: Ok, achei algo na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html?highlight=integer%20division#division) sobre a diferença de divisão de inteiros entre as versões 2 e 3 do Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se você verificar a [documentação dos tipos numéricos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=arithmetic#numeric-types-int-float-complex) verá que o operador `//` contém a seguinte descrição e observação:

> **`x // y`:** floored quotient of `x` and y
>
> <sup>**...The result is always rounded towards minus infinity...*</sup>

Tradução livre:

> **`x // y`:** piso do quociente de x e y
>
> <sup>**...O resultado é sempre arredondado em direção o infinito negativo...*</sup>

Como o resultado da sua operação seria `-3/2 == -1.5`, se você aplicar a [função piso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parte_inteira) ([`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor) no python), ou arredondá-lo em direção ao infinito negativo, você terá como resultado `-2`.

Você pode checar também a entrada [*"Why does -22 // 10 return -3?"*](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?#why-does-22-10-return-3) do FAQ do Python para entender melhor o que motivou essa decisão.